# oracle installer error after apt command

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, java, oracle

Whenever I execute `apt-get install` or `update` after the command log I get additional error saying that `oracle-java8-installer` can not be installed, which makes no sense at all. Here's an example:

```
sudo apt-get install automake
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
automake is already the newest version (1:1.15-4ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 66 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up oracle-java8-installer (8u151-1~webupd8~0) ...
Using wget settings from /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/wgetrc
Downloading Oracle Java 8...
--2018-02-18 20:16:16--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 2.18.76.99
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|2.18.76.99|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2018-02-18 20:16:16--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 184.86.54.138

Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|184.86.54.138|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1518977896_0b751d135285d8ae0d56692d56b93f4b [following]
--2018-02-18 20:16:16--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1518977896_0b751d135285d8ae0d56692d56b93f4b
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|2.18.76.99|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2018-02-18 20:16:17 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java  ; sudo apt-get update`

Also I tried removing 
`/var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/` directory

Comment: Read each of those error messages closely:  302 Moved Temporarily, 404 Not Found. Seems like Oracle moved their Ubuntu package repos.

Comment: @user535733 I mean, why would it display those errors anyway. I'm not doing anything with this packet

Comment: Then remove those worthless repos from your sources. An `apt update` checks every repo listed in your sources in order to build the database of available packages to calculate possible upgrades.